# Python script for Blender failed

Tags: python, blender

In Blender 2.62 I was using this script to display a point:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty, IntProperty, FloatProperty
from add_utils import AddObjectHelper, add_object_data
data0=[]
data0.append((float(69.3456), float(36.4562), float(26.8232)))
me0 = bpy.data.meshes.new( name = "point cloud0")
me0.from_pydata( data0, [], [] )
me0.update()
add_object_data(bpy.context, me0, [])
```

After having updated to Blender 2.67a the execution returns a failure and the following error is reported in the console window:

> ImportError: No module named 'add_utils'

Do you have any clue why this should not work anymore?

Thank you :)

Comment: Please include the error from the console when attempting to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing bpy_extras import at the start of the script

```
import bpy
import bpy_extras

from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty, IntProperty, FloatProperty
from bpy_extras import object_utils.object_data_add
from bpy_extras import AddObjectHelper
```

The API for add_object_data appears to have changed to object_data_add so you'll need to change that in the script too.

```
object_data_add(bpy.context, me0, [])
```

Comment: I have tried but it does not work, I still have the same error :(

Comment: Sorry just realised that add_utils was an internal module not one you created; edit answer to reflect that.